# SQL Query not working perfectly

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables Chain, Hotel and Shell. Hotel table link with Chain table and shell table link with both of tables.

Table Structure :---

**Chain** //Level 2

```
ChainID    |    ChainName
```

**Hotel** //Level 3

```
HotelID    |    HotelName    |    ChainID
```

**Shell**

```
ShellID    |    ShellName    |    Chain_Hotel_ID    |    Level
```

In Shell Table, Chain_Hotel_ID column hold (Chain and Hotel) table ChainID and HotelID and  Level Column Hold Int Value 2 and 3. Chain consider as 2 and Hotel 3

From these table i want

```
ShellID    |    ShellName    |    ChainName
```

I write a query for that but it not working as I want

```
select 
   _gs.ShellID, _gs.ShellName, _gc.ChainName 
from 
   Shell _gs, Chain _gc
where 
   _gc.ChainID in (select _lh.ChainID 
                   from Shell _ls,Hotel _lh 
                   where _lh.HotelID = _ls.Chain_Hotel_ID and _ls.Level = 3) 
   and _gs.Level = 3
```

**Sample Table Data**

Chain

```
ChainID    |    ChainName
   1       |    Sarovar
   2       |    Taj Group
   3       |    Oberoi
```

Hotel

```
HotelID    |    HotelName    |    ChainID
   1       |   RadhaRegent   |      1
   2       |   SarovarPortic |      1
   3       |   LaxmiVilas    |      1
   4       |   Taj Mumbai    |      2
   5       |   Taj Delhi     |      2
   6       |   Oberoi Delhi  |      3
```

Shell

```
ShellID    |    ShellName    |    Chain_Hotel_ID    |    Level
   1       |   Shell1        |        1             |      2
   2       |   Shell2        |        1             |      2
   3       |   Shell3        |        2             |      3
   4       |   Shell4        |        3             |      2
   5       |   Shell5        |        2             |      3
   6       |   Shell6        |        3             |      3
   7       |   Shell7        |        4             |      3
```

Output

```
ShellID    |    ShellName    |    ChainName    
   3       |   Shell3        |      Sarovar         
   5       |   Shell5        |      Sarovar         
   6       |   Shell6        |      Sarovar         
   7       |   Shell7        |      Taj Group   
   3       |   Shell3        |      Sarovar         
   5       |   Shell5        |      Sarovar         
   6       |   Shell6        |      Sarovar         
   7       |   Shell7        |      Taj Group
```

I got repeated data

Comment: please show some sample data and Expected output with sqlfiddle.com

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @Anjyr what is your expected output???

Comment: when i run this query i got repeated data,for example if nested query return 5  item then all data show 5 times.

Comment: Why DON'T YOU USE DISTINCT?

Comment: i used but not work, same output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
IF LEVEL=3
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT ShellID,  ShellName,  ChainName
FROM HOTEL JOIN SHELL
ON HOTEL.CHAINID=SHELL.CHAIN_HOTEL_ID
JOIN 
CHAIN ON CHAIN.CHAINID=HOTEL.CHAINID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just join tables in given sequence: Shell -> Hotel -> Chain.

Here is the code example:

```
SELECT 
    s.Id AS ShellID, s.Name AS ShellName, c.Name AS ChainName 
FROM #shell s
INNER JOIN #hotel h ON h.Id = s.HotelId
INNER JOIN #chain c ON c.Id = h.ChainID
WHERE s.Level = 3
```

Full listing to test:

```
CREATE TABLE #chain (Id INT, Name varchar(50))
GO
INSERT INTO #chain VALUES (1, 'Sarovar'), (2, 'Taj Group'), (3, 'Oberoi')
GO

CREATE TABLE #hotel (Id INT, Name varchar(50), ChainId INT)
GO
INSERT INTO #hotel VALUES 
    (1, 'RadhaRegent'   , 1), 
    (2, 'SarovarPortic' , 1), 
    (3, 'LaxmiVilas'    , 1),
    (4, 'Taj Mumbai'    , 2), 
    (5, 'Taj Delhi'     , 2), 
    (6, 'Oberoi Delhi'  , 3)
GO

CREATE TABLE #shell (Id INT, Name varchar(50), HotelId INT, Level INT)
GO
INSERT INTO #shell VALUES 
    (1, 'Shell1', 1, 2), 
    (2, 'Shell2', 1, 2), 
    (3, 'Shell3', 2, 3),
    (4, 'Shell4', 3, 2), 
    (5, 'Shell5', 2, 3), 
    (6, 'Shell6', 3, 3),
    (7, 'Shell7', 4, 3)
GO

SELECT 
   s.Id AS ShellID, s.Name AS ShellName, c.Name AS ChainName 
FROM #shell s
INNER JOIN #hotel h ON h.Id = s.HotelId
INNER JOIN #chain c ON c.Id = h.ChainID
WHERE s.Level = 3

DROP TABLE #chain;
GO
DROP TABLE #hotel;
GO
DROP TABLE #shell;
GO
```